# CouchDB get all Special Characters

Tags: view, couchdb, character

I need to get all the special characters from a view.

I have documents like this:

- doc.name: ""
- doc.name: " "
- doc.name: "+Name"
- doc.name: "*Name"

I try this params:

```
startkey: 'null', endkey: '@'
```

and

```
startkey: '\u0000', endkey: '\u0040'
```

But I can't get the contacts starting with '+' or '*'.

This is my view:

```
"function(doc) { if (doc.name) { emit(doc.name.charAt(0).toLowerCase(), doc) }}"
```

My final idea is get all characters not beginning with letters.

How many request I need to do for this and which params should I use?

Comment: I did a few test, and if I use:

`startkey: '', endkey: '9'`

I get almost all the special characters, now I just need to get the 'null'.

I try pass null in the startkey but don't work.

Any ideias?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find the way to do this, first to get all special characters I do:

> startkey: '', endkey: '9'

But like this I don't get the doc when the key don't exist or is null, because my view, so I change my view to:

> "function(doc) { if (doc) { if (doc.name)
>   { emit(doc.name.charAt(0).toLowerCase(), doc) } else {  emit('', doc) }
>   } }"

And like this I can get everything.

I don't know if this is the best way to do this, but it's working.